# PHP: What templating language utilizes <%= variable %>

Tags: php

In similar posts, I've seen Django mentioned, but it uses curly brackets and not <>

I have a variable that is displaying numbers like:

> 10.0000

I am trying to get it to display the equivalent of `number_format()` in PHP - but I don't know what language this is to achieve it.

```
<%= number_format(variable,2); %>
```

was not successful.  Nothing in the error logs saying why/what was wrong, the page just broke.

For reference, when I view the source code of the page I see this code raw, it doesn't obfuscate like PHP does.

Comment: The percent signs look like ASP -- your question is vague, how do you not know what language to use for that formatting, but you are still running the page somehow?

Comment: well yes, but we cant see your code, and while template X may use that structure so may template z,d,e,ty,u and Y so no one can know which it is. Also it may not be any open source template library at all

Comment: I posted a code sample in the title.  As  I mentioned in a previous comment, the tpl file came in an existing code system.  It isn't something I wrote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's http://www.embeddedjs.com/ thanks to [jade template tag bracket percentage definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256371/jade-template-tag-bracket-percentage-definition)

I originally missed this thread as stackoverflow doesn't recognize <% as a search term.  Located the thread via searx.

Comment: I can't yet accept this as an answer. So if anyone else comes across this thread, it's this.

Comment: so not php at all then

Comment: No, I included PHP in the original question since the codebase is PHP, assuming it may be some templating type for PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Might be Twig, it's a templating engine for PHP.

It supports the <% %> syntax and has the number_format() function

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/

Comment: The system uses twig for .tpl files (this code is in a .tpl file), but the others have strictly html & php in them.  I used searx and found this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28256371/jade-template-tag-bracket-percentage-definition

Answer (score 0):

Could be twig as mentioned above, is the common .erb syntax in ruby.

Comment: @RiggsFolly, he mentions Django in his original question and asks what templating language uses `<%= %>`. Django is python, embedded ruby isn't really out of the question here.